# Spring Security CORS issue when passing Authorization header

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, docker, spring-security, cors

I had wasted lot's of time fixing this issue, but none of the existing solutions work in my case.
Let me explain you the server set up I have.
I have 2 docker containers, one for angular app (nginx - url - http://localhost:8080) and spring boot application (tomcat - url - http://localhost:8081).
This app is using Oauth2 jdbcToken authentication for API request.

This app is a simple user registration app.

I could register a new user since the register url is not secured and not passing any Authorization header.
But once when user logs in the CORS issue kick in. below I have listed the errors.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/v1/api/group/find/shib' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Let me tell you what I had done to resolve this.
In angular HTTP request I have added the following headers.

```
'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+this.token(),
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : "*",
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, Authorization',
"Access-Control-Expose-Headers" : "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, Authorization"
```

In spring boot I added @CrossOrigin / @CrossOrigin("http:localhost:8080") on Rest controllers added with a CORSFilter

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {


    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, Authorization");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

After all the trial and error, I am still getting the same error

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check.

Comment: headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost:8081/v1/api/group/find/shib"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8081/v1/api/group/find/shib: 0 Unknown Error"
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
__proto__: HttpResponseBase

Comment: @sideshowbarker No HTTP status code is coming

Comment: See the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42021652/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/43559441/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42208796/441757

Comment: No luck with it. I have tried it

Comment: @JohnThomas As sideshowbarker already wrote, you have to show request and response with headers. For example a screenshot of your dev tool in your browser (F12). Also show your Spring Security configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I read and understood much more on preflight requests and the way it work.
A quick thought i had was to let OPTIONS request to go through so i had added the following code to my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"*").permitAll()//allow CORS option calls
    .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
}
```

And no extra headers from Angular ui except Authorization.

I hope this works for everyone. I know now that OPTIONS are vulnerable, but this was just a quick workarount.
Please suggest me if you have a better, safer solution.

Comment: When an `AUTHORIZATION` header is added to a request, the browser will automatically do a pre-flight OPTIONS request. The server must respond with proper CORS headers. Otherwise the browser will block access to the response. An OK  status response from an OPTIONS request is mandatory.