# How can I make CrossOrigin with Springboot 1.2.8

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors

I am using spring boot 1.2.8 but class `import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin` is not present. What is the best way to do that without this class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Security CORS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286549/spring-boot-security-cors)

Comment: Btw: why 1.2.x ?

Comment: I suggest you update to 1.5.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below bean configuration in your application main class:

```
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
    public class MyConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
            return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addMapping("/api/**").allowedOrigins("*").maxAge(3600);
                }
            };
        }
    }
```