# Angularjs form urlencoded with basic authorization not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, spring-boot

I tried to call an external API written in java spring with cors enabled from my angularjs app but i get 403 forbidden error while trying to make a request to the server.

My angularjs controller

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  var vm = this;
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + 'd2ViX2FwcDo='
  vm.fnlogin = function(item) {

    var postData = {

      'username': item.email,
      'password': item.password,
      'grant_type': 'password'
    }
    $http({
      url: 'http://sample.herokuapp.com/oauth/token',
      method: 'POST',
      data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(postData),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }).then(function() {

    })

  }
})
```

I am getting the below errors

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
>
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:51396' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403

Any help will be really appreciated and i am using angular 1.6.4

P.s : If i make a request using postman then i am able to generate oauth tokens but when i call from my angular app i get error.
Thanks

Comment: Try this answer, I think it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource and maybe this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs

Comment: @maydawn any similar solutions available for angular because i tried most of 'em.The one you gave is for ajax request ?

Comment: Try adding this header: 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' to the request. I'm sadly not very knowledgeable on the subject of CORS

Comment: @maydawn already did that see the controller code which i posted above

Comment: Is CORS enabled on the server ?

Comment: @maydawn yes since it works with postman i am sure it is enabled but when i make calls from my angular app i get the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148822/discussion-between-melvin-and-maydawn).

Comment: @Melvin You should enable cors in java web api to solve problem

Comment: @hsnbl i did that and its working fine when i call from a rest client tool but it fails when i do so from my web app

Comment: It will work fine with postman and fiddler even cors is not enabled in web api you are calling this web api method with xhr and it needs to enabled cors

Comment: You could try these methods to enable CORS in Spring Boot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286549/spring-boot-security-cors