# spring boot security oauth2 preflight issue

Tags: java, spring, security, oauth-2.0

I have problem with preflight in springboot security. When I send request from postman all is ok but when I try to get the token from ts code I got this error

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
```

I tried to resolve this problem by this solutions
[other solution on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286549/spring-boot-security-cors)
and 
[spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html)

I don't know the problem is in ts or spring. I put the code below:

```
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
public login(email, password) {
  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('username', email);
  params.append('password', password);
  params.append('grant_type', 'password');
  let headers = new Headers({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With,content-type',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true ,
   'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("client:clientpassword")});
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  console.log('http://localhost:1818/oauth/token', params.toString(), options);
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:1818/oauth/token', params.toString(), options);
}
```

and spring code

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("/**");

            }
        };
    }

}




@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
        //other config
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
    {

        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("/**"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "PUT"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

I'm new in spring security and I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Of course the second class has different name than first. I pasted it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I put rest of spring security code because maybe there is an error. I was looking for answer in other similar stack post but neither of these solutions works in my problem.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class Oauth2AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public Oauth2AuthServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                  @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("client")
                .secret("clientpassword")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password","authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(28*24*3600);
    }

    @Bean public TokenStore tokenStore() { return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource); }

}



@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Oauth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public Oauth2ResourceServerConfig(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT email, password, enabled  FROM users WHERE email=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?");
                //.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/new").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved 
I added

```
    @Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class WebSecurityConfig implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");
        if(request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name())){
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value());
        }else{
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}
}
```