# Getting CORS error while accessing rest-api through angular 6

Tags: rest, angular6

Getting CORS error while accessing rest-api through angular6

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../../test.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-component',
  templateUrl: './view-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-component.component.css']
})
export class ViewComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  username:string="";
  response:any;
  public httpOptions : any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  search(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/restapiapp/webapi/profiles')
    .subscribe((response)=>{
      this.response=response;
      console.log("Got the response");
      console.log(this.response);
    })
  }

}
```

getting error on my console

SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'http://localhost:4200' did not find 'http://localhost:4200' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin  resource at 'http://localhost:8080/restapiapp/webapi/profiles'.

error: ProgressEvent

headers: Object
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/restapiapp/webapi/profiles: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost:8080/restapiapp/webapi/profiles"

**proto**: Object

Comment: Does your API support CORS? This might highly not be `angular HttpClient` issue

Comment: how can I add CORS to my api??

Comment: Is your API build with NodeJs, .Net?, Spring? ...? That should be another question?

Comment: it is on spring-boot

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720552/enabling-cors-globally-in-spring-boot

Comment: it is working by just adding CrossOrigin annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working by just adding CrossOrigin annotation