# CORS Error - Spring Boot Security + HTTPs Redirect

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, https, cors

I can't make HTTPs work correctly with CORS in Spring Boot Security. I've searched and tried different solutions around the web and StackOverFlow, but I've reached a point where I don't know what to do.

I keep getting this error from an Angular FrontEnd app (Firefox):
*Request from another blocked source: the same source policy prevents reading the remote resource at http://172.20.3.9:8080/api/auth/signin (reason: the CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is missing). [Know more]
Cross-origin blocked request: The same origin policy does not allow the reading of remote resources at http://172.20.3.9:8080/api/auth/signin. (Reason: CORS request without success).*

I have a Bean definition to implement HTTPs redirection within my Tomcat like this:

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory servletContainer(){
TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
@Override
protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
collection.addPattern("/*");
securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
}
};
tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
return tomcat;
}

private Connector redirectConnector(){
Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
connector.setScheme("http");
connector.setPort(8080);
connector.setSecure(false);
connector.setRedirectPort(8444);
return connector;
}
```

Also I have a WebSecurity class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with my CORS Filter and overriding configurate

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
config.setAllowCredentials(true);
config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
config.addAllowedHeader("*");
config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
return new CorsFilter(source);
```

This method  is simplified right now. I've test a lot of configurations: with/without .cors(), channelSecure and so on.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
.permitAll()

http.addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

I have also tried to define @CrossOrigin in the controller/method. My current configure method without HTTPs redirection Works fine, no CORS problem:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().anonymous();

            http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

So I guess the problem is the combination of Spring Security and the HTTPS Redirect in Tomcat. Could anybody help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: 3 years later, but I've got almost the same problem. Spring boot, HTTPS, redirect, CORS, and Angular, and the same error. Did you find out what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create the following class

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I have tried also to set up different alternatives like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286549/spring-boot-security-cors but it's the same result. I think it's a bug or something, I have tried almost all the available options without success: Login Angular frontend localhost:4200 -> http://192.168.1.10:8080/api/auth/signin. (Cause:  CORS request without success) etc

Thanks for your response
Anyway, WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated.