# Response status 200, but still got CORS error in Angular 8

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, cors, jwt

I have a problem with CORS error in my Angluar 8 app.

I receive response from server with status 200 and valid JWT token which, I think, means server is properly configured, but still got error in console:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

The Angular app is running locally on my machine on port `4200`

The server is my own Spring Boot app with Security, running also locally on port `8080`

I have implemented custom Security Filter to handle CORS:

```
@Component
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "180");

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

And added in Security config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
    private final RestAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
    private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final String secret;
    private final TenantFilter tenantFilter;
    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;
    private final UserTenantRelationRepository userTenantRelationRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler,
                          RestAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler,
                          CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                          @Value("${jwt.secret}") String secret, TenantFilter tenantFilter, CorsFilter corsFilter, UserTenantRelationRepository userTenantRelationRepository) {
        this.authenticationSuccessHandler = authenticationSuccessHandler;
        this.authenticationFailureHandler = authenticationFailureHandler;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.secret = secret;
        this.tenantFilter = tenantFilter;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.userTenantRelationRepository = userTenantRelationRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, SessionManagementFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(tenantFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilter(authenticationFilter(userTenantRelationRepository))
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), userDetailsService, secret))
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
    }
```

As I mentioned before, I receive response 200 and valid JWT token, so I am very confused about it.

**EDIT**

Ok, so I had read about preflight request that you mentioned and fixed my filter to handle this request.

Now it looks like this:

```
@Component
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization, content-type, xsrf-token");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

And configuration is now:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(tenantFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilter(authenticationFilter(userTenantRelationRepository))
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), userDetailsService, secret))
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
    }
```

Thank you all for your tips.

Comment: Can you post code for login controller?

Answer (score 1):

if your cors request is other then **GET** the browser will issue an option request ([preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)) and it will not send authentication headers or anything like that. So in your security configuration you need to allow anonymous option request for that url.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provided example code for the OP to do this in spring boot.

Comment: I have 0 experience with java or ant or spring. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286549/spring-boot-security-cors)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do the Cors configuration in your backend using the `FilterRegistrationBean`. Usage would be as follows,

```
@Bean

public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

    config.setAllowCredentials(true);

    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");

    config.addAllowedHeader("*");

    config.addAllowedMethod("*");

    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

    FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>(

            new CorsFilter(source));

    bean.setOrder(0);

    return bean;

}
```

Import using,

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
```

Do this inside your WebConfig.java file that has the `@Configuration` annotation.