# Spring Security JWT login endpoint throws 403 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, auth0

I'm following this article: https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/

Making a security layer to protect my Rest API.

I requested to the `/login` URL but it returns 403.

`JwtGenerator`:

```java
public class JwtGenerator extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {


    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JwtGenerator(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            User user = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(request.getInputStream(), User.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(),
                            user.getPassword())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        authResult.getAuthorities().forEach(authority -> System.out.println(authority.getAuthority()));
        String token = JWT.create()
                        .withSubject(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .withClaim(AUTHORITIES_KEY, authResult.getAuthorities()
                        .stream()
                        .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(Algorithm.HMAC512(JWT_SECRET.getBytes()));

        response.setHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

And `WebSecurityConfig`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurityConfig(@Qualifier("UserDetailsService") UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users/sign-up").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JwtGenerator(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JwtVerifier(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}
```

As far as I know, the `/login` endpoint is created automatically by Spring Security and the `JWT Generator` is the modification code for that endpoint. It might be lacking `permitAll()` for this URL method in `WebSecurityConfig`?

When I request to that URL, it returned to me 403 without any message:

[image: Postman]

Even the log:

```
2020-03-30 07:52:59.916  INFO 1712 --- [nio-1408-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-30 07:52:59.953  INFO 1712 --- [nio-1408-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 36 ms
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_5_, user0_.created_at as created_2_5_, user0_.updated_at as updated_3_5_, user0_.biography as biograph4_5_, user0_.date_of_birth as date_of_5_5_, user0_.displayname as displayn6_5_, user0_.email as email7_5_, user0_.password as password8_5_, user0_.username as username9_5_ from users user0_ where user0_.username=? or user0_....
```

Comment: I even add `antMatcher("/login").permitAll()` and still doesn't work.

Comment: You might wanna read up on CORS.There might be a preflight OPTIONS call which gets blocked. Maybe you check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286549/spring-boot-security-cors

Comment: @jdickel I did the same as that question. It has no effect at all. By the way thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the spring loglevel to debug? Then you should receive a reason why it returns 403.