# Spring Boot CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors, jwt, http-status-code-401

My Spring Boot Rest API is secured by JWT token. I have the following CORS setting

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {  registry.addMapping("/api/**").allowedMethods("*").allowedOrigins("*").maxAge(3600);}};
}
```

and in security config

```
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll();
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/**").permitAll();
        httpSecurity.antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
```

Now I am able to authenticate and get JWT token, get , post data from my angular  2 app running in different domain. Now I want to handle token expiry by catching HTTP status 401. 
I do get status 401 from spring boot, when token expired. But 401 error does not reach angular, because browser complains about CORS

> Failed to load http://ipaddress:8010/api/sy/code/findAll?page=0:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401

how to configure spring boot to send Access-control-Allow-origin for 401.
I do have allow allowedOrigins("*") configuration. but that does not seem to work. Any help.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092082/2708210 might help

Comment: This helped https://stackoverflow.com/a/41000211/1057094  thanks