# How to fix CORS when using WebSecurity.ignoring()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm building a platform using Spring with authorization via JWT.
In gateway service I have custom filter (based on BasicAuthenticationFilter) for parsing token but it should be invoked only for routes marked in security config as `.authenticated()` so routes which can be access by anyone are added to `WebSecurity.ignoring()`.

The problem is that adding path to `WebSecurity.ignoring()` also disable CORS config for it and `OPTIONS` request is not returning `Access-Control-*` headers.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            // Auth service
            .antMatchers("/auth/login", "/auth/renew")
                .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/logout", "/auth/session/**")
                .authenticated()

            // User service
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/")
                .permitAll()
            .antMatchers( "/user/confirm/**", "/user/recover", "/user/validate/**")
                .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/", "/user/change/**")
                .authenticated()

            // further part of routes...

    http
            .formLogin()
                .disable()
            .logout()
                .disable();

    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtKey));

    http.csrf().disable();

    http.cors();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
            // Auth service
            .antMatchers("/auth/login", "/auth/renew")

            // User service
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/")
            .antMatchers( "/user/confirm/**", "/user/recover", "/user/validate/**")

            // further part of routes...
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(corsOrigins);
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Is there any way to bypass only specific filter for some paths?

**-SOLVED-**

I've solved my problem by enabling `WebMvc` and adding cors configuration (previous may be deleted).

```java
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowCredentials(true)
            .maxAge(3600);
}
```

Comment: Could you use some of these [minimal examples](https://github.com/jrichardsz/spring-boot-templates) and share us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question is interesting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091524/spring-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present

Comment: @MilyGosc: Add your "solved" part as an answer instead of the edit!

Comment: Adding `@EnableWebSecurity` to security config (along with corsConfigurationSource) and `@CrossOrigin` to controller helped