# Problem Cors: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, spring, cors, same-origin-policy

I cannot resolve this error; I added
*@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")*
but the error still persists.

**RestAPIController.java**

```js
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


(origins = "http://localhost:4200") 
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/customer")
public class RestAPIController {
    
    @Autowired
    CustomerServices customerServices;
    
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<Message> addNewCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        try {
            Customer returnedCustomer = customerServices.saveCustomer(customer);
            
            return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Upload Successfully!", 
                                            Arrays.asList(returnedCustomer), ""), HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("Fail to post a new Customer!", 
                                            null, e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);           
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    
}
```

what do you advise me to do? Thank you

I have tried in every way, I have found and tried several examples on this site but the problem still appears.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091524/spring-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: The same question was already Answered. [Please take a look at it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091524/spring-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present#35092082)

Comment: I have tried in all ways, I have tried several examples here but the problem still results. Otherwise I would not have asked this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question.

You should add this overide method in Config class which extend `WebMvcConfigurer`

```
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .maxAge(3600);
   }
```

Comment: I have tried in all ways, I have tried several examples here but the problem still results. Otherwise I would not have asked this question

Comment: also add http.cors() in SecurityConfig. If it still do not work. Just push link to source code here. maybe someone can help.