# Allow CORS with Spring Security 6.1.1 with authenticated requests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I've upgraded from Spring Boot 2.5 to 3.1, which comes with Spring Security 6.1.1. Calls to the login authentication REST service work just fine, but all requests to other REST controllers that require authentication token are being blocked by the CORS policy.

I have followed the directions in Springs documentation to disable CORS, but it does not work.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html#page-title

Here is the current configuration that I have:

```java
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","PUT","PATCH","DELETE","OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(false);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                //.cors(cors -> cors.disable()) <<--- does not work as documented
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                    .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(SYS_ADMIN_PATTERNS).hasAuthority("SYSTEM_ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

I have tried setting disabling the CORS using the .cors(cors -> cors.disable()), which did not disable CORS filtering.

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors(cors -> cors.disable()) 
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                    .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(SYS_ADMIN_PATTERNS).hasAuthority("SYSTEM_ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

Also tried adding @CrossOrigin annotation tags to the REST controller classes, which did nothing. Also verified that I have the @Configuration annotation with the @EnableWebSecurity annotation (another change in Spring Security).

What am I missing?

Comment: Show us the browser error

Comment: How is that authentication token sent by the client to the server? Via the `Authorization` header, perhaps? If so, you'll need to allow this request header in your CORS config.

Comment: I updated the CORS config to allow the Authorization header and it worked, kinda. The preflight returned a HTTP 200, but the actual GET returned a 403, which I verified it had a valid token in the Authorization header. So, I logged out and now the login is getting the CORS error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/api/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 9):

After struggling for couple of days, I come to some conclusion, like how this is working.

I was facing a 401 error in my preflight request

I followed the documentation code since the preflight request was causing the problem, I added one more requestMather which is specifically for the preflight request

```
 .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
```

[image]

and add @CrossOrigin to your controllers at class level

Comment: Thanks so much, adding this

   .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())

and annotating my Controller classes with @CrossOrigin works.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could get it to work is to disable CORS in the SecurityFilterChain and annotate the RestController with @CrossOrigin. If you have the CorsConfigurationSource configured the @CrossOrigin annotations are ignored (or at least have no effect) and it simply doesn't work with Spring Security 6.1.

Here is the working configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                    .requestMatchers("/api/auth").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(SYS_ADMIN_PATTERNS).hasAuthority("SYSTEM_ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        ;
        SecurityFilterChain chain = http.build();
        log.info("Configured security filter chain: {}",chain);
        return chain;
    }
```

Then ensure you have the @CrossOrigin annotations on your REST controllers at the class level or individual method level.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin
public class AuthenticationController {
...
}
```

Comment: I am facing the issue, I also did the same things mentioned in the documentation and youtube tutorial out there, but the Cors configuration is unpredictable, sometimes upon disabling the Cors makes my app works as desired the next day it is not working at all with the same configuration. After disabling I enabled and used the CorsConfigurationSource object then it worked well but a moment before disabling the cors it was not working at all. The real issue is it was giving an error in the preflight request.

Comment: @user1123270 Thank you! I've been fighting with this for 1 week..

Answer (score 1):

**Just add cors method to configure cors settings:**

```
.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
```

**Here is all of my securityFilterChain:**

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())  // Add this line
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable) 
            .authorizeHttpRequests(req  -> req
                    .requestMatchers("/auth/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()

            )
            .sessionManagement(session  -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return httpSecurity.build();
}
```

**And add CrossOrigin annotation to controllers:**

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/category")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CategoryController {

    private final CategoryService categoryService;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to disable CORS in your spring security filter chain: `cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)` or explicitly permit all the Pre-Flight requests: `.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()`

As the Spring official document[enter link description here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html) says:

> CORS must be processed before Spring Security because the pre-flight request will not contain any cookies (i.e. the JSESSIONID). If the request does not contain any cookies and Spring Security is first, the request will determine the user is not authenticated (since there are no cookies in the request) and reject it.

The trick would be to just ensure that the CORS is handled first and before the Spring security is executed, and that will be done by:

1. Enable CORS default processor in spring security filter chain:

   .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
2. Configure CORS configuration in either of the recommended ways:

   Global Configuration,

   CorsWebFilter

and that would be more than enough to start your journey.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable it globally, no need for fine-grained configuration on the controller level!

If you are using Spring MVC (servlet not reactive), here is the only guide you need (updated to Spring Boot 3): https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Basically, you need to implement WebMvcConfigurer and add the method to addCorsMappings:

```
    @Component
    public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedMethods("GET","POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD");
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: This is the real answer! This was much harder than it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

Add this configuration.addAllowedHeader("Authorization") in the corsConfigurationSource() method if you have any header values like "Authorization".
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9NLz.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to add `http.headers(header -> header.addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")));` and `.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()`

You can see my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77929945/1561658)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security 6:

```
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(
                (authorize) -> authorize
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8080");
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for me:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // ...
        http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults()); // disable this line to reproduce the CORS 401
        return http.build();
    }
}
```