Adding spring security to working spring-boot app
There are two controllers web
@Controller
public class WebController {
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
    @GetMapping("/api")
    public String showForm() {
        return"bars";
    }
}

and rest
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RestBarController {
    @CrossOrigin//(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
    @GetMapping("/app")
    public List<Bar> getBars(){
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
        //LocalTime localTime = localDateTime.toLocalTime();
        
        List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i<20; i++) {
            Bar bar = new Bar();
            localDateTime = localDateTime.plusMinutes(1);
            bar.setTime(localDateTime);
            bar.setShortTime(localDateTime.format(formatter));
            bar.setBlack((int)(-Math.random()*1000));
            bar.setWhite((int)(Math.random()*1000));
            bars.add(bar);
        }
        
        
        return bars;
    }
}

and js which render data to chart with chartJS
var shortTimeLabel =[];
var blackData = [];
var whiteData = [];
var chart;
    
const apiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/app";
var response;// = await fetch(apiUrl);
var barChartData;// = await response.json();
var short_time;// = barChartData.map((x) => x.shortTime);
var black_;//_ = barChartData.map((x) => x.black);
var white_;//_ = barChartData.map((x) => x.white);

    
async function dummyChart(){
    await getDummyData();
    let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

    chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: shortTimeLabel,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Down',
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
        data: blackData,
        borderWidth: 1
      },
            {
        label: 'Up',
                backgroundColor: 'pink',
        data: whiteData,
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index'
            },
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
    }
  });
}
dummyChart();

setInterval(updateConfigByMutating, 10000);
console.log("Hello");


async function updateConfigByMutating() {
    await getDummyData();
    chart.options.plugins.title.text = 'new title';
    for (let i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
        chart.data.datasets[0].data[i] = black_[i];
    } 
    
    for (let i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets[1].data.length; i++) {
        chart.data.datasets[1].data[i] = white_[i];
    } 
    
    for (let i = 0; i < chart.data.labels.length; i++) {
        chart.data.labels[i] = short_time[i];
    } 
    
    
    chart.update();
}

    //Fetch data from dummy REST API
    async function getDummyData(){
        response = await fetch(apiUrl);
        barChartData = await response.json();
        short_time = barChartData.map((x) => x.shortTime);
        black_ = barChartData.map((x) => x.black);
        white_ = barChartData.map((x) => x.white);
        console.log(short_time, black_, white_);
        
        shortTimeLabel = short_time;
        blackData = black_;
        whiteData = white_;

    }

And it works:

But when I try to add spring security it will not work.
SecurityConfig
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // cross site request forgery
            .csrf(csrf->csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) ->
                authorizeHttpRequests
                // access to the root of our app index.html in resources/static (doesn’t work)
                .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                // acces to url /api
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasAnyRole(Role.ADMIN.name(), Role.USER.name())
                // any request should be authenticated
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(withDefaults());
            //.httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager(){

        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
            .username("admin")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build();
        
         UserDetails user = User.builder()
             .username("user")
             .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user"))
             .roles("USER")
             .build();
            
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());
        System.out.println(admin.getPassword());
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

Chart doesn't load and in browser console I see code 302 Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I'm sure that problem is in spring security configuration.

So you added security and are now surprised that the security actually works.

I added credentials to fetch() method in js but it doesn't works anyway.                         response = await fetch(apiUrl, {credentials: "include"});. They also advise me to configure csrf but if it is disabled  it can't impact to app

Adding credentials won't do much as you disabled basic auth, so without doing the login flow in your client (as you have the login form) that won't work.

There are was two problems

JS wasn't configured correctly, with fetch() method you need to send credentials
fetch(apiUrl, {credentials: "include"})

In the back end you should configure cors [this][1] helped me


    .cors(configurer -> {
                UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource configurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
                CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
                corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8080"));
                corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
                corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
                configurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
                configurer.configurationSource(configurationSource);
            })


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76682586/allow-cors-with-spring-security-6-1-1-with-authenticated-requests

