# Spring MVC CORS not working for error controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have my Spring MVC application configured to use CORS as such:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**");
}
```

This works fine for successful requests however when an exception is thrown and is picked up by my error handler, CORS headers are not added.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiErrorHandler {

   @ExceptionHandler(value = HttpClientErrorException.class)
   public ResponseEntity badRequest(Exception ex) 
   {
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(ErrorBodyWrapper.wrapErrorInJson(ex.getMessage()));
   }
}
```

Is there a reason CORS does not work for error handlers?

Thanks

Comment: CORS is a protocol to guard from cross domain requests, your @ControllerAdvice should collect exceptions from controller which is a step after the CORS check , what is the servlet container you are using? and the is the method type of the request?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I'm using the embedded tomcat. Any method type seems to fail... but I was originally using OPTIONS.

Answer (score 0):

I think by default the only method added to the mapping is GET, 
In your "addCorsMappings" try to specify the methods you want to add the header to

```
       registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD");
```

Comment: this still doesn't work for error responses. It works fine for successful responses. I am throwing the exception in an interceptor, would that make a difference?

Comment: no it wouldnt , actually the error response does not have anything to do with CORS, " return "redirect:hxxp://www.xxx.com";" is this a different domain from your server?

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring `CorsFilter` can resolve this problem.

```java
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);

        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");

        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));

        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
```