# Sending Authorization Token Bearer through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwt

I'm trying to send a Authorization Token Bearer through Javascript to a REST Endpoint, so i doing in this way:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/resourceserver/protected-no-scope',
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend : function( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( "Authorization", "Bearer " + token );
    },
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    }
```

My endpoint is running under a SpringBoot container, so i'm getting the HttpServletRequest and trying to get AUthorization Header but is always null:

```
static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        //token is always null
...
```

**Edit 1**
This is the error in Client-Side (Browser

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/resourceserver/protected-no-scope 403 ()
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/resourceserver/protected-no-scope: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403.
```

**Edit 2**
To enable CORS in backend i'm using the following annotation with spring:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600, allowCredentials = "true", allowedHeaders = "Authorization", methods =
        {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.POST})
public class MyResource {
```

**Edit 3**
I tried added the CORS in my Filter but no success:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", httpServletRequest.getHeader("Origin"));
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");


        Authentication authentication = TokenAuthenticationService
                .getAuthentication(httpServletRequest);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Header in AJAX Request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/add-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery)

Comment: Are you getting any CORS error?

Comment: Yeah, but i already solved it using this in spring-boot: @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600, allowCredentials = "true", allowedHeaders = "Authorization", methods =
        {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.POST})

Comment: @Paul i tried the solutions in this post but didn't work.

Comment: HTTP status 403 is Forbidden; sounds like you might need something else on the server-side.

Comment: Yeah, i need the Token (JWT TOKEN), but if is null i got 403 Forbidden, the server response is correct.

Comment: It shouldn't need the token for the OPTIONS preflight; if it does, something's wrong with that server-side code. I don't know anything about spring-boot.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `headers` key to add headers

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost:8080/resourceserver/protected-no-scope',
   type: 'GET',
   contentType: 'application/json'
   headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'
   },
   success: function (result) {
       // CallBack(result);
   },
   error: function (error) {

   }
});
```

You need to enable CORS on backend

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320294/5567387

Comment: I tried but continue returning null in my java endpoint. I know that problem is not in java server because if i use postman and send a request with Authorization Bearer Token everything works.

Comment: You can also copy code generated by POSTMAN and try that https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets

Comment: I edited my post with error in client-side (browser)

Comment: which means there is CORS issue. Fix on server side

Comment: debugging my server-side i need this token to validate the request but as i said, this token is always null.

Comment: Because browsers don't allow cross origin ajaz calls, copy code generated by POSTMAN and if you still face same issue then it's sure it's CORS issue. Allow your host and required headers on backend.

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas Have a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320294/5567387 also you have not shared your backend code, how are you handling CORS issue

Comment: I tried with code generated by POSTMAN and i have same issue. So i can understand thaet is a CORS issue, do you have any tip how can i allow this i spring-boot ?

Comment: I added a link in my answer but google is your friend.

Comment: I already added a CORS Config in backend, saw my editied post please

Comment: Try this https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176676/discussion-between-ronaldolanhellas-and-zohaib-ijaz).

Comment: This link https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework resolved my problem

Comment: For the comment 'You can also copy code generated by POSTMAN and try that', the resource has moved to another location:
https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Answer (score 3):

Sending the request with [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/resourceserver/protected-no-scope', { 
    method: 'GET', 
    headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before `https.get` use authorization in header.

```js
const options = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer token'
  }
}

https.get(url, options, function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
})
```