# Javascript - XMLHttpRequest post, use resonse to get

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, xmlhttprequest

this is my fist post, as I can't find any solution for my problem. (googled days now)
I'm not a programmer, I'm a good googler :)

I'm trying to login to a Website with Username, Password and some options. (/api/login/Basic)
Afterwards I'm trying to access a Site. (/api/sitemaster/run)
But here I'm getting the message: "User does not have adequate access rights"
If I do this with a browser, everything works fine.

I guess I need to pass some Authtoken to the Get request, but I have no clue.

Here my code snippet:

//this is working fine

```
const toSend = {
    email :"my@mail.com",
    force_sm_off: false,   //I have no clue (found from Net Sniffing of the original Application)
    password:"mypassword",
    username:"installer"}

const jsonString = JSON.stringify(toSend)  ;
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() ;
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0 //I have no certificate and only access the Site in my local network

xhr.open("POST", "https://192.168.2.77/api/login/Basic",false,"Provider_Engineer","mypassword" ) ;
xhr.setRequestHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json") ;
xhr.withCredentials=true ;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     const myresponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText) ; //myresponse contains: email, firstname, lastname,    roles: Array(1), token
       var myauth=myresponse.token //Saving Token for further use


   //fine until here

   //Now I'm trying to get the Page

    const xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest() ;
    process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0
    xhr1.open("GET", "https://tesla/api/sitemaster/run",false ) ;
    xhr1.setRequestHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json") ;
    xhr1.setRequestHeader ("credentials", "same-origin") ;
    xhr1.setRequestHeader ("AuthCookie", myauth) ;  //In Browser F12 I can see AuthCookie and Userrecord
    xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
         console.log(this.responseText)  //getting Message: User does not have adequate access rights
    }     
    xhr1.send(null)
};
xhr.send(jsonString) ; //Post Request, that is working fine
```

Any suggestions how I can access this site?

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

`process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0`
`xhr1.open("GET", "https://tesla/api/sitemaster/run",false ) ;`

`var myBearer= "Bearer " + myauth ;`

`xhr1.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", myBearer) ;`

found at:
[Sending Authorization Token Bearer through Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506579/sending-authorization-token-bearer-through-javascript)