# Is an authorization: bearer token the same as AWS's token authorizers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, bearer-token

Currently in my team's web app, we pass access tokens in a header called Auth: 'dfdfdf...'. We use AWS Lambda and a token authorizer to access our API gateway resources.

There is also a different type of bearer token header: Authorization: Bearer :
[Sending Authorization Token Bearer through Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506579/sending-authorization-token-bearer-through-javascript/51506645)

Is the difference only proprietary/naming, or is Amazon's token authorizer functionally different from the bearer token pattern?

Answer (score 1):

- AWS Token Authorizer follows oAuth2
- Bearer you are mentioning is Bearer token.

You can google to find differences between oAuth2 and bearer token.

I have quoted here about [Bearer token](https://oauth.net/2/bearer-tokens/#:%7E:text=Bearer%20Tokens%20are%20the%20predominant,such%20as%20JSON%20Web%20Tokens.):

> Bearer Tokens are the predominant type of access token used with OAuth 2.0.
>
> A Bearer Token is an opaque string, not intended to have any meaning to clients using it. Some servers will issue tokens that are a short string of hexadecimal characters, while others may use structured tokens such as JSON Web Tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon's token authorizer also uses Bearer token way to authenticate.

In detail,

There are two types of Lambda authorizers:

1. A token-based Lambda authorizer (also called a TOKEN authorizer) receives the caller's identity in a bearer token, such as a JSON Web Token (JWT) or an OAuth token.
2. A request parameter-based Lambda authorizer (also called a REQUEST authorizer) receives the caller's identity in a combination of headers, query string parameters, stageVariables, and $context variables.

**Also, What is Bearer Token ?**

The bearer token is a cryptic string, usually generated by the server in response to a login request. The client must send this token in the Authorization header when making requests to protected resources: Authorization: Bearer

**So, Amazon lambda authorizer can user Bearer Token method as one of the way.**