# How do I stack CORS filters for different URLs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cors

I have a Spring Boot 2 REST API as the backend for my React app. The website and API are hosted on different subdomains (`https://example.com` and `https://api.example.com` respectively), so I have set up a CORS filter to support this:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

    CorsConfiguration apiCorsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    apiCorsConfig.addAllowedOrigin("https://example.com");
    apiCorsConfig.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    apiCorsConfig.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    apiCorsConfig.setMaxAge(600L);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", apiCorsConfig);

    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean =
        new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

This works just fine.

---

I have now implemented Spring SAML to support SAML as an alternative means of authenticating against the API. All SAML endpoints are placed under `/saml/**`. The SAML authentication requests can come in from any origin, so I need to open these endpoints up to allow CORS requests from any origin.

I tried the following:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

    CorsConfiguration apiCorsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    apiCorsConfig.addAllowedOrigin("https://example.com");
    apiCorsConfig.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    apiCorsConfig.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    apiCorsConfig.setMaxAge(600L);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", apiCorsConfig);

    CorsConfiguration samlCorsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    samlCorsConfig.addAllowedOrigin(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    samlCorsConfig.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    samlCorsConfig.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    samlCorsConfig.setMaxAge(600L);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/saml/**", samlCorsConfig);

    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean =
        new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

However, this does not work, and a `403 Invalid CORS request` is returned when an unknown origin tries to access `/saml/**` endpoints.

---

I guess the issue here is that the more general `/**` pattern takes precedence, even when there is a more specific ant-pattern `/saml/**` matching the request.

I don't want to configure all other endpoints explicitly to allow the website origin, but want it to be a catch-all for requests not matching any other CORS configuration.

---

**How can I allow any origin to access `/saml/**` while still only allowing `https://example.com` to access all other enpoints `/**`?**

Comment: I think you can annotate your Controller class which used @RequestMapping('/saml') with @CrossOrigin('*')

Comment: There is no explicit SAML controller, since these endpoints are handled by Spring SAML.

Comment: That answer solves multiple pre-defined allowed origins protecting a single path patterns, which is not the same as my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS with spring-boot and angularjs not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319396/cors-with-spring-boot-and-angularjs-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CorsConfiguration`s are registered by adding them to a `LinkedHashMap` inside the `UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource`. This means the order is preserved and it's just a matter of adding the `CorsConfiguration`s in the right order:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

    CorsConfiguration samlCorsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    samlCorsConfig.addAllowedOrigin(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    samlCorsConfig.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    samlCorsConfig.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    samlCorsConfig.setMaxAge(600L);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/saml/**", samlCorsConfig);

    CorsConfiguration apiCorsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    apiCorsConfig.addAllowedOrigin("https://example.com");
    apiCorsConfig.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    apiCorsConfig.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    apiCorsConfig.setMaxAge(600L);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", apiCorsConfig);

    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean =
        new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can extend `UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource`  and override `getCorsConfiguration`:

```
public class CustomeUrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource extend UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource{

        @Override
        @Nullable
        public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String lookupPath = this.urlPathHelper.getLookupPathForRequest(request);
            if(this.pathMatcher.match("/saml/**",lookupPath)){
              return this.corsConfigurations.get("/saml/**");
             }
            return super.getCorsConfiguration(request);
    }
```

your configuration should be something similar to:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    CustomeUrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new CustomeUrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

    CorsConfiguration apiCorsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    apiCorsConfig.addAllowedOrigin("https://example.com");
    apiCorsConfig.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    apiCorsConfig.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    apiCorsConfig.setMaxAge(600L);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", apiCorsConfig);

    CorsConfiguration samlCorsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    samlCorsConfig.addAllowedOrigin(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    samlCorsConfig.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    samlCorsConfig.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    samlCorsConfig.setMaxAge(600L);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/saml/**", samlCorsConfig);

    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean =
        new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this should solve the issue. However, I don't like having the endpoint configuration duplicated in separate classes. An idea would be to have an `UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource` implementation that goes through the different `CorsConfiguration`s in the order they are added (instead of looping through the entry set in an undefined order like the `UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource` does). You could then add the more specific `CorsConfiguration`s first, and if none is found if would fall back to the most general `/**` one.

Comment: Well I'll be damned. This is already the case, since the `CorsConfiguration`s are added to a `LinkedHashMap` that keeps it's order. Then it's just a matter of adding the `CorsConfigurations` in the right order. Thanks for helping me find this!