# Java Spring JPA CORS errors

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Java Spring JPA application and I want to allow every mapping (/test, /test/1, /test/1/test, etc) for the host: `http://localhost:4200`. However with the following code I get a CORS error on every call.

My main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addMapping("*").allowedMethods("OPTIONS", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200").allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

I tried `registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("OPTIONS", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200").allowedHeaders("*");` which works for /test but not for /test/1/test. Do I have to add a mapping for every route? Like: `addMaping("/**")`,`addMaping("/**/**")`,`addMaping("/**/**/**")` or can I have one single mapping to allow every route?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS with spring-boot and angularjs not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319396/cors-with-spring-boot-and-angularjs-not-working)

Comment: Make this : allowedOrigins("*")