# blocked by CORS policy handling if we using front-end Angularjs and back-end spring-boot?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, cors

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.----------.com/efsapi/api/AdvanceQuote?
>           segmentcode=--&customercode=--&por=--&fdc=--&toscode=--' from origin 
>           'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight 
>           request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
>           is present on the requested resource (edited)

This error in i am facing in angularjs and we are using java as backend. tried  the below code in front-end

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest
```

Could you please tell how to handle this CORS error? (Platforms Angularjs & Java)

Comment: It may resolve by using **@CrossOrigin** at api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS with spring-boot and angularjs not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319396/cors-with-spring-boot-and-angularjs-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you face is that the java backend blocks the client request and you need to allow the origin of the client in the backend.

### From the spring cors guide

**Enabling CORS for a single method:**

> So that the RESTful web service will include CORS access control headers in its response, you just have to add a @CrossOrigin annotation to the handler method:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    System.out.println("==== in greeting ====");
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
}
```

**Enabling CORS globally:**

> As an alternative to fine-grained annotation-based configuration, you can also define some global CORS configuration as well. This is similar to using a Filter based solution, but can be declared within Spring MVC and combined with fine-grained @CrossOrigin configuration. By default all origins and GET, HEAD and POST methods are allowed.

```
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
        }
    };
}
```

For reference take a look at the original source: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24654998)

Comment: @nbk thanks for the reminder I revised the answer and included the relevant excerpts from the guide.