# Angular fontend connect springboot problem

Tags: angular, spring-boot

i'm writing a project with angular and springboot.

I got the problem. when i click the submit button ,angular should send a post request and the application should print "post api working!!!"

But it's not works,the application print nothing.

my api code as belows:
[image]

i use the formdata to get inputdata,and my angular post request:
[image]

[image]

CAN ANYONE TELL ME WHAT AM I DOING WORONG?
THANKS!

Comment: Check the network tab for api calling. It maybe possible that your java application is not allowing angular app to make requests i.e., CORS origin issue for requests from port 4200 to 8080

Comment: **CORS origin issue** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319396/cors-with-spring-boot-and-angularjs-not-working/32320294#32320294

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with CORS add this code to you Bootsrap class

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200" or different address) 
                        .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST");
            }
        };
    }
```

But as I understand it, judging by the console, the error is not in CORS. Check the mappings, maybe the endpoint is incorrect? Maybe you have @RequestMapping above your Java class?

Why are there no errors in the console at all if the program does not work?