# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing REACT

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, react-native, cors

I am building a react application on top of spring boot. I have been getting these errors on my browser when I try to make a put request to localhost:8080

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/products. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/products. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

I have set up @CrossOrigin on my server-side for localhost 3000.

Been trying to fix this for a while by adding headers, proxies and even using the firefox CORS everywhere. Nothing seems to be working.

Please see my front end code below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Card, Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import Toasting from "./Toasting";
export default class AddProducts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.startState;
    this.state.toast = false;
    this.productChange = this.productChange.bind(this);
    this.submitProduct = this.submitProduct.bind(this);
    var config = {
            headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
        };
  }

  startState = { id: "", name: "", brand: "", made: "", price: "" };

  componentDidMount() {
    const productId = this.props.match.params.id;
    if (productId) {
      this.findProductById(productId);
    }
  }

  findProductById = (productId) => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/products/" + productId)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data != null) {
          this.setState({
            id: response.data.id,
            name: response.data.name,
            brand: response.data.brand,
            made: response.data.madein,
            price: response.data.price,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error has been caught: " + error);
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  reset = () => {
    this.setState(() => this.startState);
  };

  submitProduct = (event) => {
    //Prevent default submit action
    event.preventDefault();

    const product = {
      id: this.state.id,
      name: this.state.name,
      brand: this.state.brand,
      madein: this.state.made,
      price: this.state.price,
    };


    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/products", product)

    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data != null) {

        this.setState({ toast: true });
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ toast: false }), 3000);
      } else {
        this.setState({ toast: false });
      }
    });
    this.setState(this.startState);
  };

  productChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  productList = () => {
    return this.props.history.push("/");
  };

  updateProduct = event => {
    //Prevent default submit action
    event.preventDefault();

    const product = {
      id: this.state.id,
      name: this.state.name,
      brand: this.state.brand,
      madein: this.state.made,
      price: this.state.price,
    };

    ***************THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS**********************************************
    axios.put("http://localhost:8080/products", product, this.config).then((response) => {

      if(response.data != null) {
        this.setState({ toast: true });
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ toast: false }), 3000);
        setTimeout(() => this.productList(), 3000);
      } else {
        this.setState({ toast: false });
      }
    });
    this.setState(this.startState);
  };

  render() {
    const { name, brand, made, price } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ display: this.state.toast ? "block" : "none" }}>
          <Toasting
            toast={this.state.toast}
            message={"Product has been successfully saved!!!"}
            type={"success"}
          />
        </div>

        <Card className={"border border-dark bg-dark text-white"}>
          <Card.Header align="center">
            {" "}
            {this.state.id ? "Update a Product" : "Add a Product"}
          </Card.Header>
          <Form
            onSubmit={this.state.id ? this.updateProduct : this.submitProduct}
            id="productFormId"
            onReset={this.reset}
          >
            <Card.Body>
              <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group controlId="formGridName">
                  <Form.Label>Product Name</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={this.productChange}
                    required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    className={"bg-dark text-white"}
                    placeholder="Enter Product Name"
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Form.Row>
              <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group controlId="formGridBrand">
                  <Form.Label>Brand</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    type="text"
                    name="brand"
                    value={brand}
                    onChange={this.productChange}
                    className={"bg-dark text-white"}
                    placeholder="Enter Brand Name"
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Form.Row>
              <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group controlId="formGridMade">
                  <Form.Label>Made</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    type="text"
                    name="made"
                    value={made}
                    onChange={this.productChange}
                    className={"bg-dark text-white"}
                    placeholder="Made in"
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Form.Row>
              <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group controlId="formGridPrice">
                  <Form.Label>Price</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    type="text"
                    name="price"
                    value={price}
                    onChange={this.productChange}
                    className={"bg-dark text-white"}
                    placeholder="Product Price"
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Form.Row>
            </Card.Body>
            <Card.Footer>
              <Button size="sm" variant="success" type="submit">
                {this.state.id ? "Update" : "Submit"}
              </Button>{" "}
              <Button size="sm" variant="info" type="reset">
                Undo
              </Button>{" "}
              <Button
                size="sm"
                variant="info"
                type="button"
                onClick={this.productList.bind()}
              >
                Products
              </Button>
            </Card.Footer>
          </Form>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Please see my product Controller class server-side below

```
package ie.sw.spring;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;


@RestController
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService service;

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> list() {
        return service.listAll();
    }

    // Get products by their id
    @GetMapping("/products/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> get(@PathVariable Long id) {
        try {

            Product product = service.get(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<Product>(product, HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {

            return new ResponseEntity<Product>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }

    // Handle post requests
    @PostMapping("/products")
    public void add(@RequestBody Product product) {
        service.save(product);
    }

    // Update a product
    @PutMapping("/products/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody Product product, @PathVariable Long id) {
        try {
            Product existProduct = service.get(id);
            service.save(product);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/products/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        service.delete(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should not append CORS `headers` from frontend. So, remove that. After that, you need to make sure that the URL `http://localhost:8080/products/SOME_ID_HERE"` works in a tool like [postman](https://www.postman.com/). You should debug the CORS issue only after it works on postman. So, does it work on postman?

Answer (score 3):

```
***************THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS**********************************************
    axios.put("http://localhost:8080/products", product, this.config).then((response) => {
       ...
    }

    @PutMapping("/products/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody Product product, @PathVariable Long id) {
       ...
    }
```

---

I think you have missed the path variable while creating the request with `axios.put`. Either you should remove the `@PathVariable Long id` or you have to pass the id in the request.

```
Option 1

axios.put("http://localhost:8080/products/" + productId, product, this.config).then((response) => {
   ...
}

@PutMapping("/products/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody Product product, @PathVariable Long id) {
   ...
}
```

---

```
Option 2

axios.put("http://localhost:8080/products", product, this.config).then((response) => {
   ...
}

@PutMapping("/products")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody Product product) {
   ...
}
```

Also, change the @CrossOrigin as follow

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", methods = {RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE}, allowedHeaders = "*", allowCredentials = "true")
```

You may also have look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319396/cors-with-spring-boot-and-angularjs-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` to the **package.json** file. That helped me. I had the same problem.

Comment: I did indeed does nothing

Comment: Did you tried to create a custom server, and set up a proxy?

Comment: No, how would I go about that?

Comment: Is your backend on NodeJS/Express.js?

Comment: No my backend is spring boot

Comment: Hmm, I don't have experience with Spring, so I cannot help you, but you should check your Spring config again. Maybe something is blocking on the backend. 

Also you can try to add `{"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With"}` to headers too.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alen

Answer (score 0):

> @CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")

is wrong, try

> @CrossOrigin("http://localhost:8080")

Answer (score 0):

> I have set up @CrossOrigin on my server-side for localhost 3000.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at **http://localhost:8080**/products. (Reason: CORS
> header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Your error is for `localhost:8080`.

Solutions :

1. Set in your server-side `localhost:8080`.
2. You could, which is not recommended, set `*` in your server-side, it
   sets all urls.
3. Or the other solution is to change your port in your front app to the
   one you've set in your back.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to run locally have you tried the chrome addon?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

Answer (score 0):

Two possible answers:

1. Configure cors in you WebConfig file. From spring [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-cors)

Your method would be like:

```
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

    registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("https://localhost:3000/**")
        .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE","GET","POST");
    // Add more mappings...
}
```

2. For testing, change your @CrossOrigin to all origins:

   @CrossOrigin(origins =*)

If it works, then it's just a detail somewhere. Can you test it and tell us?

Looking at the documentation, they always leave explicit 'origins="address"'. In your cause it would be:

```
  @CrossOrigin(origins ="http://localhost:3000")
```

Comment: In `CrossOrigin`, [`value`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html#value--) is [aliased](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/spring-aliasfor-annotation-example/) to [`origins`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html#origins--) so I think `@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")` and `@CrossOrigin(origins ="http://localhost:3000")` should do the same think, shouldn't they?

Comment: Yes. It is the same, but when I am in front of some trouble, I everything very clear. This is why I said it in the last argument

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Using `@CrossOrigin` was already suggested by another answer

Comment: In `CrossOrigin`, [`value`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html#value--) is [aliased](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/spring-aliasfor-annotation-example/) to [`origins`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html#origins--) so I think `@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")` and `@CrossOrigin(origins ="http://localhost:3000")` should do the same think, shouldn't they?

Answer (score -1):

i think cors on localhost doesn't work .

Have a look at below pages .

[Why does my http://localhost CORS origin not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work)

[https://medium.com/swlh/avoiding-cors-errors-on-localhost-in-2020-5a656ed8cefa#:~:text=1.,setting%20in%20Create%20React%20App&text=%22proxy%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2F,CORS%20error%20will%20be%20resolved](https://medium.com/swlh/avoiding-cors-errors-on-localhost-in-2020-5a656ed8cefa#:%7E:text=1.,setting%20in%20Create%20React%20App&text=%22proxy%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2F,CORS%20error%20will%20be%20resolved).