# origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:How to solve this in angular?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, rest, typescript2.0

I am new to full-stack application .I had used angular11 in Front-End and  Spring-boot Gradle project with JPA rest-service in Back-End.

### **My Angular Method**

```
addTodos(todo:Todos)
    {
    return this.http.put('http://localhost:8082/addTodo',JSON.stringify(todo))
     }
```

### **My Rest Service**

```
@PutMapping(path="/addTodo" ,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Todo> addTodo(@RequestBody Todo todo) {

    todoservice.addTodos(todo);
    return new ResponseEntity<Todo>(todo,HttpStatus.OK);
    
}
```

My Error in browser is:Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8082/addTodo' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How to solve it?. Any help will be appreciable,thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320294/2815219

Comment: thanks ,one solution worked among these.