# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/blog/updatePost/2' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, annotations

Even though I used @CrossOrigin annotation this error still appears. Spring boot app is running on 8080 port and react app is running on 3000 port.

[image: image of backend controller]

Error:

[image: Error in console]

If further information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Which HTTP method are you trying to access? POST or PUT

Comment: Are you using spring security in the backend?

Comment: This is a known issue while using spring-boot please checkout the last part of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46372630/3651739

Comment: I tried to do a update using PUT method. and I use spring security in backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using spring security.
@CrossOrigin filter might have a lower precedence over spring security filters. Try to configure CORS using spring security.

Comment: I resolved the problem. I put the way I have done it below as an answer. thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue with the answer given by @Sanura. Then blockage done by the CORS is avoided.

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/login", "/auth/register","/post/savePost", "/post/**", "/post/getPost/{id}","/post/updatePost/{id}")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

I added the routes to the configure method as above.

The below mentioning code sample also can be used instead of this.

```
package com.myapp.springboot.configs;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
    
    @Configuration
    public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/*").
            allowedOrigins("*").
            allowedMethods("*").
            allowedHeaders("*").
            allowCredentials(true);
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your support.