# CrossOrigin code in spring to remove the index error

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to get rid of the `cors` error in the index but it's not working. I tried using the code `@CrossOrigin(origins="*")` but it didn't work. Is it because I'm using version 21 and in the video it uses version 17?

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")

public class Controller {
@Autowired
private Repositorio acao;

@PostMapping("/")

public Cliente cadastrar(@RequestBody Cliente c ){
    return acao.save(c);
}
@GetMapping("/")
public Iterable<Cliente> teste(){
    return acao.findAll();
}

@PutMapping("/")
public Cliente editar(@RequestBody Cliente c){
    return acao.save(c);
}
@DeleteMapping("/{codigo}")
public void remover(@PathVariable long codigo){
    acao.deleteById(codigo);
}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQqnC.png)

Comment: Does this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319396/cors-with-spring-boot-and-angularjs-not-working

Comment: It didn't work because in the video I put it I only use https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqhogtMZCq0
jump to minute 3:48 it just uses @CrossOrigin(origins="*") and it works but on mine it doesn't